# how to manually empty moosefs trash folder to save space

Tags: moosefs

I found that moosefs trash take too much of my disk space. according to moosefs documentation, it will keep it for a while in case user want it back. But How to clean it up manually to save space?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to purge MooseFS' trash, you need to mount special directory called "MooseFS Meta".

Create mountdir for MooseFS Meta directory first:

```
mkdir /mnt/mfsmeta
```

and mount `mfsmeta`:

```
mfsmount -o mfsmeta /mnt/mfsmeta
```

If your Master Server Host Name differs from default `mfsmaster` and/or port differs from default `9421`, use appropriate switch, e.g.:

```
mfsmount -H master.host.name -P PORT -o mfsmeta /mnt/mfsmeta
```

Then you can find your deleted files in `/mnt/mfsmeta/trash/SUBTRASH` directory. Subtrash is a directory inside `/mnt/mfsmeta` named `000..FFF`. Subtrashes are helpful if you have many (e.g. millions) of files in trash, because you can easily operate on them using Unix tools like `find`, whereas if you had all the files in one directory, such tools may fail.

If you do not have many files in trash, mount Meta with `mfsflattrash` parameter:

```
mfsmount -o mfsmeta,mfsflattrash /mnt/mfsmeta
```

or if you use Master Host Name or Port other than default:

```
mfsmount -H master.host.name -P PORT -o mfsmeta,mfsflattrash /mnt/mfsmeta
```

In this case your deleted files will be available directly in `/mnt/mfsmeta/trash` (without subtrash).

In both cases you can remove files by simply using `rm file` or undelete them by moving them to `undel` directory available in trash or subtrash (`mv file undel`).

Remember, that if you do not want to have certain files moved to trash at all, set "trash time" (in seconds) for these files to `0` prior to deletion. If you set specific trash time for a directory, all the files created in this directory inherit trash time from parent, e.g.:

```
mfssettrashtime 0 /mnt/mfs/directory
```

You can also set a trash time to other value, e.g. 1 hour:

```
mfssettrashtime 3600 /mnt/mfs/directory
```

For more information on specific parameters passed to `mfsmount` or `mfssettrashtime`, see `man mfsmount` and `man mfstrashtime`.

Hope it helps!

Peter